# notepad++ regex add character between two values

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having a difficult time with regex expressions.  I am trying to create a table for a wiki page.

I have:

```
{| class="wikitable" border="1"
|+ Printer connectivity troubleshooting
! Serial Number !! IP Address
|-
|G90001 192.168.10.21
|-
|G90002 192.168.10.22
|-
|G90069 192.168.10.19
|-
```

I need:

```
{| class="wikitable" border="1"
|+ Printer connectivity troubleshooting
! Serial Number !! IP Address
|-
|G90001 || 192.168.10.21
|-
|G90002 || 192.168.10.22
|-
|G90069 || 192.168.10.19
```

I was able to get the pipes at the beginning of the line in using find and replace and a macro, but I can't come up with a formula that works in the slightest for the pipes between the items.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Are there a lot of items?  If it's only three it would probably be faster to just type it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\|G9\d+) (.+)
```

To replace with

```
\1 || \2
```

Or a more generic match (not limiting to starting with G9)

```
^(\|\w+?) (.+)
```

Comment: You're my hero!  I knew I needed the separate expressions, but I couldn't get it work.  I had a space between them, like you do and yours didn't work either just now, so that made me think about what could be wrong.  I removed the space  between the two and used your expression and it worked great!  Thank you!!!!